# EF does not lazy load Views

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dbcontext, entity-framework-4.3

I have a method which gets the whole data from a View inside my database:

```
public IQueryable<vw_FullWebIgnoringApprovalStatus> GetAllFullWebIgnoringApprovalStatus() 
{
    IQueryable<vw_FullWebIgnoringApprovalStatus> query = 
        Context.vw_FullWebIgnoringApprovalStatus;

    return query;
}
```

When I execute the following method, it immediately executes the query which it shouldn't:

```
var model = _repo.GetAllFullWebIgnoringApprovalStatus()
    .Where(x =>
        (!reid.HasValue && !destid.HasValue && !coid.HasValue) ||
        (reid.HasValue && x.Reid == reid.Value) ||
        (destid.HasValue && x.Destid == destid.Value) ||
        (coid.HasValue && x.Coid == coid.Value)
    );
```

It should have lazy loaded the query and it didn't. Is it related to view? I am using EntityFramework.4.3.1.

Comment: I agree it shouldn't "immediately execute the query". What makes you think it does?

Comment: @NicholasButler SQL Profiler which has shown me that this action gets 248 rows from the table which took approx. 6 seconds to complete.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor why do you need POCO model class?

Comment: @tugberg you need each nav property marked with virtual for lazyloading

Comment: @LukeMcGregor I see but there is no navigation property inside this model. `string`, `int`, `int?`, `bool?` are the types all it has.

Comment: Are you sure you're not enumerating the query? What happens if you set `model = null;` right after the declaration with the `Where` clause?

Comment: @NicholasButler I don't follow. That code is the only action and it is immediately executed.

Comment: The code you've posted shouldn't execute any SQL, so there must be something else going on.

Comment: What does the vw_FullWebIgnoringApprovalStatus property look like?

Comment: @ArthurVickers `public DbSet<vw_FullWebIgnoringApprovalStatus> vw_FullWebIgnoringApprovalStatus { get; set; }`

Comment: @NicholasButler I think so but what? That's the whole point of this question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that HasValue is recognized by LINQ to Entities beause there is no way to convert that into SQL. Therefore I think in this case, L2E has to execute the query before it can evaluate HasValue. I haven't seen this particular behavior before. I thk you need to find another way to express your nullability test. And i'd be interested to see the SQL.

Here's one interesting idea:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/56484ed7-9664-44f4-84a0-69da3901c817

There are all kind of weird behaviors with LINQ around nullables so you have to really pay attention to the results -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738687.aspx

hth
julie

Comment: Ah, yes. That might be it. I will test against it and see if it is the problem. thanks!

Comment: Ok, this was the issue. As soon as I removed the LINQ `Where`clause, it started lazy loading. But, apparently I have other issue with my paging logic I triggered after the above query. Thanks again!

Comment: I think you know this but I just want to be sure that future readers don't mistake this as caused by having a Where clause. The issue ought to be specific to the HasValue inside the Where clause. Can you verify that this works with a simpler Where clause, which doesn't cause it to execute the query until you specifically do something to trigger executiong.

Comment: Yes, it lazy loads with a simpler where clause like: `_repo.GetAllFullWebIgnoringApprovalStatus().Where(x => x.CoID == 1000);`